# XSD "version" attribute semantics

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1, xsd-1.0

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ... version="xxx">
```

The XSD specification https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#declare-schema does not specify the semantics for the `version` attribute:

> The other attributes (`id` and `version`) are for user convenience, and this specification defines no semantics for them.

Nor does that the W3C versioning guide https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-guide2versioning/.

Is there a consensus arising whether this attribute should be used for specifying the version of the XML Schema document (e.g. `2.3.1`), or for the version of the XSD language used to write the schema document (i.e. either `1.0` or `1.1`)? Or is the semantics choice still on the designers/developers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xs:schema/@version` attribute is used for specifying the version of the XSD being developed, not XSD 1.0 vs 1.1.  [Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) or any other user-defined semantics may be used.  As your apropo quote indicates, it is up to the user to define.

To specify XSD 1.0 vs 1.1, XSD 1.1 provides [conditional inclusion](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cip), which can be used on any XSD element, including the `xsd:schema` root element.  For example, an XSD that requires assertions could indicate the need for XSD 1.1 like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <!-- -->
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This is what I thought too, but when I was searching on the web, I found several links like [this one](http://wiki.archive.iatistandard.org/standard/revision/1.03/changes_specification#add_a_schema_version_attribute_to_the_root_element), but none explicitly supporting my view. Which caused me to ask the question.

Comment: That [link](http://wiki.archive.iatistandard.org/standard/revision/1.03/changes_specification#add_a_schema_version_attribute_to_the_root_element) also supports your view.  The *standard* to which they recommend use of `xs:schema/@version` refers to their [**IATI standard**](http://wiki.archive.iatistandard.org/standard/start), *not* to the W3C XML Schema standard.